# JsonSerializer per request context

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, autofac

I have to apply different rules of serialization depending on the context pass on a http request. I was thinking that the cleanest way was to do this with a JsonConverter that will be hook from the startup of my application.

```
class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var context = serializer.Context;
        ...
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var context = serializer.Context;
        ...
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        ...
    }
}
//in the startup i am just registering this converter by
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new List<JsonConverter>()
                {
                    new MyJsonConverter()
                }
            };
```

The issue is at this point my expectation was to have the `serializer.Context` to be the context of my request. But is actually empty.

How can I make this to be set in a per request basis, so I can use it on the converter? is any possibility to do this at a asp.net level? or maybe using autofac to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll want to install the nuget package "Autofac.Integration.Mvc"

then you can add .InstancePerHttpRequest() into your registrations
https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/CE22CC19.htm

Second, in your registrations, you'll have something like this

```
builder.Register(c => new JsonSerializer(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings)).InstancePerHttpRequest().As<JsonSerializer>();
```

The lamda will execute each HttpRequest and give you the current context, assuming you can retrieve it.

You'll need to modify your code to take JsonSerializer in the constructor, instead of each method.  This will trigger autofac to give you a new instance per HttpRequest.  Your code will look something like this now...

```
class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;
    public MyJsonConverter(JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        _serializer = serializer;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value)
    {
        var context = _serializer.Context;
        ...
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue)
    {
        var context = _serializer.Context;
        ...
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @rateus, thanks for your answer. I am not clear on one thing. As is the `SerializerSettings`who actually holds the instance of the Serialising settings is done at startup configuration, there is only one instance. I was thinking if it was a way to resolve in the `JsonSerializer.Context` used in the converter the context per request.

Comment: @Kanekotic I've updated my answer to what I think you need, I didn't realize at first you were using NewtonSoft Json